# NestJS `class-validator` and `class-transformer` not validating value objects when used inside an Object with key-value

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I have base class:

```
export class AddServiceDto {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  SvcTypeCode: string;

  @IsDefined()
  @IsBoolean()
  WillPayFtc: boolean;
}
```

It's working great on its own, NestJS is appropriately validating the user's input if it satisfies this class when this is used as a DTO.

Now, I have another Controller that would allow you to add multiple services, but it should be "keyed" by a specific string, something with the shape of:

```
type keyedServiceGroup = {
  [key: string]: AddServiceDto;
}
```

the actual payload on this Controller would look something like this:

```
{
    "AccountType": "PERSONAL",
    "serviceGroups": {
        "01": {
            "SvcTypeCode": "01-001",
            "WillPayFtc": true,
        },
        "02": {
            "SvcTypeCode": "02-001",
            "WillPayFtc": true,
        },
        "03": {
            "SvcTypeCode": "03-043",
            "WillPayFtc": true,
        }
    },
}
```

so the Class/DTO i wrote for this new controller looks like this:

```
export class AllServiceRequestDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    enum: AccountType,
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(AccountType)
  AccountType: AccountType;

  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsObject()
  serviceGroups: keyedServiceGroup[];
}
```

the problem is, it's not validating if each object inside the `serviceGroups` satisfies the `AddServiceDto`, for example, if I remove the `"WillPayFtc"` from the payload, the request simply goes in without any error. Compared to when I'm using the individual controller, it would fail the request which is the correct behavior.
Is there something that I should use for the `serviceGroups` so NestJS validates it properly?

Thanks!

Comment: I look at the example (the actual payload) and see that the serviceGroups is not even an array.